# Import csv into phpmyadmin and skip first colum

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

Since i'm not a db geek i need some help to import a csv dump into my db.

I have a db that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6mS4.png

I need to import a csv dump that looks like this:

```
br,dc634e2072827fe0b5be9a2063390544
bs,7c9df801238abe28cae2675fd3166a1a
bt,6920626369b1f05844f5e3d6f93b5f6e
```

How can I skip the first colum and import only the combination and the hash?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkTMw.png

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i have fixed this by making a simple c# app that adds the id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing through phpmyadmin, mention the column names as comma seperated just before the go button